# Develop a Facebook application with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I want to develop a asp.net application to Facebook.

Since most of the examples in Facebook are in PHP ( which I'm not familiar with), I wanted to know if it is possible to make a server side in asp.net.

I created a Facebook application but when I click on the url to reach it, I get an "uploading" message  that eventually disappears and I get an error message in the application section of the page itself.

I read about the c# SDK and sort of things but I can't see any result from the server - even a simple text message.

Comment: In order to work out what is going wrong with your code, you will need to include specific code examples of what you've tried, and where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the [facebook SDK C# example](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample) and make sure to implement your own "AppId" and "AppSecret" values as provided by the [Facebook Developer App](http://www.facebook.com/developers/).

Comment: Hi, Yea, I did it. I think I'm missing something.
Let me just write what I did.
I set a url ( an IP, not a domain) to the: "Canvas URL" and to the "Secure Canvas URL".
I placed the application in the directory specified in the URL.
When I go to the link of my application, I get a "uploading (0%)..." message for a few seconds and then I get a message:

Comment: The message that I get is "This webpage is not available".